# Facebook accesstoken update after adding new permission

Tags: android, facebook, access-token

In my app, I am requesting new permission if user want to post comment. If new permission is given, will the access token change?

How should I save the token?

I save the token when log in at the first time:

```
 AccessToken mtoken=loginResult.getAccessToken();
 AccessToken.setCurrentAccessToken(mtoken);
```

But when I restart the app, it throws null exception when I try to access the token:

```
AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().getPermissions()
```

Comment: you can save the token in shared pref , when token changes then update the shared pref vlaue

Comment: Ok, thank you, I thought facebook has method to do that

Comment: then will my token change if I have new permission?

Comment: Yes if there is change in the token then it will notify you . AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().getPermissions() check if condition with null value if(dummyValue!=null){//then do your stuf}

Comment: sharedprefence method can only store string, but to publish comment, I need accesstoken type, how to solve this problem?

Comment: you can check this link , with there source file ,it will help you out https://github.com/sromku/android-simple-facebook

Comment: thank you! I will take a look